# Retreive Values From `NSMutableDictionary` in the order they are added

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I am adding some key and values in `NSMutableDictionary` but while retrieving the `allKeys` that I am not getting the same order in that I was adding. Is there any way to get the same order or any other way to save the values.

Please note: I do not want to sort the array of `allKeys`. I want a specific order in which I added.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order.  You need a separate array of keys as well as the dictionary.  This question has been asked many times; please search before posting.

Comment: You might want to have a think about how you got to this problem in the first place, and change your approach to whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure you want an `NSMutableDictionary` and not an `NSMutableOrderedSet`

Comment: Or better, consider either having a parallel array or you may want to create your own composite object to do the right things.